# Kivy tutorial buttons don't print

Tags: python, kivy

I'm working through the Kivy tutorial, [programming guide](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/events.html#dispatching-a-property-event), and find the following code is not actually printing the button position anywhere, as far as I can tell---that is, the btn_pressed() method doesn't seem to do anything.

```
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
 from kivy.uix.button import Button
 from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
 from kivy.properties import ListProperty

 class RootWidget(BoxLayout):

     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
         self.add_widget(Button(text='btn 1'))
         cb = CustomBtn()
         cb.bind(pressed=self.btn_pressed)
         self.add_widget(cb)
         self.add_widget(Button(text='btn 2'))

     def btn_pressed(self, instance, pos):
         print ('pos: printed from root widget: {pos}'.format(pos=pos))

 class CustomBtn(Widget):

     pressed = ListProperty([0, 0])

     def on_touch_down(self, touch):
         if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
             self.pressed = touch.pos
             # we consumed the touch. return False here to propagate
             # the touch further to the children.
             return True
         return super(CustomBtn, self).on_touch_down(touch)

     def on_pressed(self, instance, pos):
         print ('pressed at {pos}'.format(pos=pos))

 class TestApp(App):

     def build(self):
         return RootWidget()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     TestApp().run()
```

Does anyone have any hints or ideas why this isn't working?  Is this the intended behavior and I missed something or is there an error in the tutorial?

Specifically, while the instructions above produce buttons that can be clicked and flash---there doesn't seem to be any output corresponding to the method:

```
 def btn_pressed(self, instance, pos):
     print ('pos: printed from root widget: {pos}'.format(pos=pos))
```

Maybe it's printing black on black?

Comment: Code works as expected for me. Can you provide log output from console as well?

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a log display when I run this, just a bunch of info, debug, warnings---but they don't change on click.  Where are you seeing the output of "printed from root widget:" displayed?

Comment: Updating the above---I think I was unclear in what wasn't working.

Comment: After running application from command line with `python test.py` and clicking on the button in the middle I see output from both `btn_pressed()` and `on_pressed()` provided in command line, same as with any other `print` usage. You wrote "buttons that can be clicked and flash" - are you actually only trying to click left and right ones? `btn_pressed` is bound only to button inside which doesn't flash and doesn't even look like button since it's just a Widget subclass with some functionality added.

Comment: Okay, yes, that was it.  The blank middle area is a button and prints to stdout when I click that area---I was clicking the named buttons on the left and right.  Thanks.  I just misunderstood the tutorial and code.

Comment: If you phrased that as an answer, "It works as expected if you expect the empty middle part to be a button"  ;)  I'd accept it and close this!  Thanks again, I was very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The seemingly blank, unlabeled spot in the middle is the button that accepts location and prints location to the console.  I was clicking on the buttons labeled "btn" and didn't notice this place existed.

This part of the tutorial is demonstrating how you can make custom buttons that do stuff precisely like this.  It would be more clear if this were labeled, but that should be doable by looking at the API.

Anyway, the code is working as expected.